# Display Manager name instead of Manager Id in Oracle ADF

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Employees table contains -

```
 Employee_Id,
 Manager_Id,
 First_Name,
 Last_Name
```

I want to display manager name instead of id

LOV cannot be used

Current Query in VO:

```
   SELECT 
      Employees.EMPLOYEE_ID, 
      Employees.FIRST_NAME, 
      Employees.LAST_NAME, 
      JobObject.JOB_TITLE, 
      Employees.COMMISSION_PCT, 
      Departments.DEPARTMENT_NAME, 
      Departments.DEPARTMENT_ID, 
      JobObject.JOB_ID, 
      (First_Name||' '||Last_Name) AS VIEW_ATTR, 
      Employees.SALARY, 
      Employees.MANAGER_ID
 FROM EMPLOYEES Employees, 
      DEPARTMENTS Departments, 
      JOBS JobObject
WHERE Employees.DEPARTMENT_ID = Departments.DEPARTMENT_ID
```

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you want to show Manager Name along with employee details. Is so then following query will be helpful.

```
  SELECT emp.EMPLOYEE_ID,
   emp.FIRST_NAME,
   emp.LAST_NAME,
   JobObject.JOB_TITLE,
   emp.COMMISSION_PCT,
   dept.DEPARTMENT_NAME,
   dept.DEPARTMENT_ID,
   JobObject.JOB_ID,
   (emp_manager.First_Name || ' ' || emp_manager.Last_Name) AS manager_name,
   emp.SALARY
 FROM EMPLOYEES emp
   JOIN DEPARTMENTS dept ON (emp.department_id = dept.department_id)
   JOIN JOBS JobObject ON (emp.job_id = JobObject.job_id)
   JOIN EMPLOYEES emp_manager ON( emp.manager_id = emp_manager.employee_id  )
```

Answer (score 0):

If  I understood correctly ,the reason why you get nothing is related to join,when you use commas in the FROM clause may you get problem.
and for managername if you have a manager table you have to inner join with that or try this:

```
 SELECT Employees.EMPLOYEE_ID, 
   Employees.FIRST_NAME, 
   Employees.LAST_NAME, 
   JobObject.JOB_TITLE, 
   Employees.COMMISSION_PCT, 
   Departments.DEPARTMENT_NAME, 
   Departments.DEPARTMENT_ID, 
   JobObject.JOB_ID, 
   (Employees.First_Name+' '+Employees.Last_Name) AS ManagerName, 
   Employees.SALARY, 
   Employees.MANAGER_ID
   FROM EMPLOYEES Employees,
inner join
 DEPARTMENTS Departments on Employees.DEPARTMENT_ID = Departments.DEPARTMENT_ID
 left outer join 
JOBS JobObject on JobObject.Job_Id=Employees.Job_Id
where Employees.MANAGER_ID is not null and Employees.MANAGER_ID in (EMPLOYEE_ID from employees)
```

Comment: In the problem statement I want to display manager name instead of id..I was trying with nested subquery like:
Employees.SALARY, 
       Manager_Name = select FIRST_NAME FROM Employees e1
       JOIN Employees e2
       ON e1.manager_id = e2.employee_id
FROM EMPLOYEES Employees..........Yours query doesn't fetch ManagerName

Comment: do you have manger table? if you have my code not works correctly

Comment: @rahul is it ok?

Comment: I changed it check it please and tell me abouth result